# Creating makefile c++ that stores .o to a directory

Tags: c++, c, makefile

Here is an example of how my datas are stored :

```
\Program
     main.cpp
     makefile
     \Part1
          file1.cpp
          file1.h
          file2.cpp
          etc
     \Part2
          file3.cpp
          file4.cpp
          file4.h
          etc..
     \Part3
          file5.cpp
          file5.h
          etc..

     \Objects
          file1.o
          file2.o
          file3.o
          file4.o
```

I think you understood.

My problem is that whatever I try my makefile does not work

> clang: error: no input files

or

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

Well, I tried to learn by myself how to build a makefile. I leant the easiest way like :

```
all:exe
exe: Objects/file1.o Objects/file2.o Objects/file3.o Objects/file4.o Objects/file5.o .....
     $(CPP) $(LFLAGS) Objects/file1.o Objects/file2.o Objects/file3.o ... -o exe
```

And then, for each .o I ask the makefile to do like :

```
Objects/file1.0: Part1/file1.cpp
         $(CPP) $(CFLAGS) -o $(OBJ/file1).o Part1/file1.o
```

But I keep having this issue :

> makefile:XX: warning: overriding commands for target `.o'
>   makefile:XX: warning: ignoring old commands for target`.o'

For every file

I tried to learn how to build makefile more proprelly but it's quite difficult. I tried many, many things and it doesn't work.

Here is what I mean when I say a proper way to write makefile

```
ALL_CPP=Part1/*.cpp, Part2/*.cpp, Part3/*.cpp, Part4/*.cpp
CPP_FILES := $(wildcard $(ALL_CPP))
OBJ_FILES = $(patsubst $(ALL_CPP),Objects/%.o,$(CPP_FILES))

main: $(OBJ_FILES)
    g++ -o $@ $^

Objects/%.o: Animal/%.cpp
    g++ $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
Objects/%.o: Enclos/%.cpp
    g++ $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
Objects/%.o: Menu/%.cpp
    g++ $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
Objects/%.o: Zoo/%.cpp
    g++ $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

But of course it doesn't work.

My question is :

How to create a makefile which would work in an environment like mine (with different subfolder) and which would store the .o in a dedicated folder.

I worked using xcode but unfortunately I want a menu where you can navigate using the arrows which doesn't work on the xcode console.

Comment: Objets != Obje**c**ts

Comment: Yes sorry, I'll edit. The mistake came because of the translation I did because english isn't my mother language

Comment: Showing **why** the second example doesn't work would have been helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second attempt was pretty close.

The problem is with this line

```
OBJ_FILES = $(patsubst $(ALL_CPP),Objects/%.o,$(CPP_FILES))
```

The first argument to `$(patsubst)` is the pattern to match but `$(ALL_CPP)` isn't a pattern. You want `dir/%.c` for each directory there. You *could* make that list of patterns if you really wanted to but there's a better way to do it.

You really have *two* transformations here. One to replace *any* leading directory with `Objects` and one to replace `.cpp` with `.o`.

So do them separately.

Use a [Substitution Reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Substitution-Refs) for the first part:

```
OBJ_FILES := $(CPP_FILES:.cpp=.o)
```

and the `notdir` and `addprefix` [file name functions](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#File-Name-Functions) for the second part:

```
OBJ_FILES := $(addprefix Objects/,$(notdir $(OBJ_FILES))
```

and that should make things work.

Comment: First, thank you for taking time to explain me. If I understand well, I have 2 ’OBJ_FILES’ ? It worked I guess, in a file I have ’Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:’ but I think that's my fault (even if I don't understand why because it works perfectly well on XCode)

Comment: Another question, what is the difference between %.o and *.o ? It looks like it does the same thing

Comment: I did it, it now works but not using your method because it gave me errors... i did a one line for 12 files g++ -o exe main.cpp folder/file1.cpp etc

Comment: You have one `OBJ_FILES` variable you just assign to it twice. The second time using the first value as part of the "input". I didn't change anything about your compilation lines. If those worked before they will work now. If not then that's something else you need to fix but it doesn't affect what I wrote here.

Comment: See [Using Wildcard Characters in File Names](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Wildcards) for how make uses `*` in file names. Whereas `%` is the "wildcard" character in patterns, both for functions and for pattern and implicit rules (you can read more about those in the manual also).